# Highest date in java

Tags: java

How to get highest date among given set of dates in java in a jsp

Answer (score 6):

```
Set<Date> dates;
Date max = Collections.max(dates);
```

Comment: This is a great start. Doing it *inside* a JSP (if that's *really* what one wants to do) is a lot harder.

Comment: @erickson: I've never used JSP, but I thought that within the `<% %>` tags you could just put Java code.  What's the complicating factor?

Comment: No actually i am getting the dates from java program and getting it in a jsp as a String.then type mismatch pb is there

Comment: @user: I don't know what you're trying to say.  If you're having trouble with my solution above please update (edit) your question to provide the relevant details.  Use full words.  Be explicit.  Include error messages.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about scriptlets. I don't use them because putting Java code in my JSPs quickly turns into a mess. I only use tag files and tag libraries. Creating a tag for something like this is a lot of overhead. Normally, I have control over the objects getting rendered in the JSP, so I'd expose this "maximumDate" as a property on one of those objects, rather than actually computing it with an expression in the JSP.